# How to strip div classes when using explode from an external site

Tags: php, explode

I would like to remove all div classes and id's and just have the content preferably as a list.

I would appreciate the help as I am currently banging my head against the wall right now.

```
$result = file_get_contents("https://www.lottery.ie/dbg/results/view?game=daily-million&draws=1") ;

$bonusNumber = $ex3 = '';
/*         * **** Result Get With url********* */
if ($result) {
    $ex1 = explode('<section class="matching-draw">', $result);
    if ($ex1['1']) {
        $ex2 = explode('<h4>', $ex1['1']);
        $ex3 = explode('</h4>', $ex2['1']); /*                 * **Date get here*** */
    }
}

if (!empty($ex3)) {
    $dateVal = $ex3['0'];
    $allNumber = explode('<h5>WINNING NUMBERS</h5>', $ex3['1']);
    $allNumber1 = explode('<div class="pick-number">', $allNumber['1']); //pr($allNumber1);


    foreach ($allNumber1 as $no) {  
        $ball[] = explode('</div>', $no);
    }
    $ex4 = explode('<h5>BONUS</h5>', $ex3['1']);
    if ($ex4) {
        $ex5 = explode('</div>', $ex4['1']);
        if ($ex5) {
            $ex6 = explode('<div class="pick-number">', $ex5['0']);
            $bonusNumber = $ex6['1']; /*                     * ****Final Bonus Number******** */
        }
    }
}


if (!empty($bonusNumber)) {
    echo 'Winning Numbers<br/>';
    echo $ball['1']['0'] . ' ' . $ball['2']['0'] . ' ' . $ball['3']['0'] . ' ' . $ball['4']['0'] . ' ' . $ball['5']['0'] . ' ' . $ball['6']['0'] . '<br/>';
    echo 'Bonus<br/>';
    echo $bonusNumber;
```